# Connect to OCI from Netsuite Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Is there a way I could connect to OCI resources using a Suitescript? I need to upload a file to OCI Object storage from suitescript.

I am trying to leverage the OCI-SDK to achieve this. But I am not sure how to include this in my Suitescript.